# how to get the text that has been selected from listitem of an unordered list in content page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to know which listitem is selected from the unordered list which is there in the master page.

So basically when i click on any list item from the content page i need to know the is of the item that is clicked and perform some action.

i tried the following code but i am not able to add the click action and get the id of the selected list.

```
Control list = this.Master.FindControl("mainsection").FindControl("maindiv").FindControl("sideNav").FindControl("sideNavMenu");
```

Please help me

Edited code :

```
<ul id = "sortable1">
  <li id = "Coffee">Coffee</li>
  <li id = "tea">Tea
    <ul>
      <li id = "Black tea">Black tea</li>
      <li id = "green tea">Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id = "Milk">Milk</li>

<li style="display: list-item;" class="emptyMessage">No more contacts available</li></ul>
```

Comment: it seems right whatever you've done we need master page HTML to figure out what's going wrong...

Comment: @Curiousdev Thanks for the quick reply. The items in the unordered list are dynamically loaded. I need to know which list is being clicked on the content page and get its id

Comment: i would say better to use jQuery for this [find this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gztRq/2/) and then follow @Karan 's idea..

Comment: On click of list item you can store value in some hidden field and on server side simply get value from that field.

Comment: When i see this nested FindControl monster i recommend to use a property in your master like `SideNavMenu`. Then you just need to cast the `Master` to the actual type and you can access it. Your approach can break easily in future if you change the structure minimally

Comment: @Karan : Could you tell me how can i achieve this may be an example can help me

Comment: @Curiousdev But how can i get the value in the content page?

Comment: @TimSchmelter could you provide me an example

Comment: @ashish: Search for _"Content page interacts with master page"_ here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36055/%2FArticles%2F36055%2FInteraction-Between-Content-Page-and-Master-Page

Comment: Hi @Curiousdev that worked but the javascript function only gets executed once because update panel is restricting it. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: @Curiousdev this is solved but when i have nested unordered list it executes the javascript twice and loads the parent list

Comment: it would be better to drop your code whatever you've done till now in new question so we can help you out..

Comment: @Curiousdev below is the code

<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea
    <ul>
      <li>Black tea</li>
      <li>Green tea</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>

I am using the same javascript function that you sent me. When i am selecting the inner list for eg BlackTea then javascript first returns blacktea and then returns tea(as it is the parent) I only want black tea to be returned

Comment: @ashish find updated [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gztRq/998/) just add `e.stopPropagation();` and add `e` as parameter in click invoke function.. read more about `e.stopPropagation();` [HERE](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Great..........

Answer (score 0):

Add `<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnListId" runat="server"></asp:HiddenField>` in your html. Give `clickable` class to each `li` you want to save `id`.

Add following javascript.

```
$(function() {    
    $("li.clickable").click(function() {
        $('#' + '<%=hdnListId.ClientID%>').val(this.id);
    });
});
```

On server side, You can simply get value from `hdnListId.Value`

Comment: Hi Karan this works  only for the first click but when i select second item from the list it doesnt show the value

Comment: You can check with `debugger` in javascript code for second click whether it is triggering `$("li.clickable").click(function()` or not.

Comment: I think the reason is because i have an update panel. How can i do this with update panel

Comment: You have to put `hdnListId` inside Updated panel

Comment: i tried that but that didnt work. I think the function is only getting executed once

Comment: I think update panel is not allowing. is there any other solution?